# Select rows where time portion of datetime column is 00:00

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, time

I have a table with a `registrationDate` column having `datetime` data type. I need to find all rows where time portion of that column is `00:00:00.000`.
For example :

```
registrationDate
-----------------------
2019-03-20 00:00:00.000
```

I need to query something similar as below :

```
select *
from table
where registrationDate like '%00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Please don't think of datetime values as strings. They are not strings, and `LIKE` will not work (as I'm sure you've already tried). What you're looking for is data that has a time component of midnight.

Comment: (I talk about this in [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).)

Answer (score 7):

You can cast datetime as time:

```
WHERE CAST(registrationDate AS TIME) = '00:00'
```

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis you can't use 0. What is a 0 time? Try it. It won't convert no matter how you go about it.

Comment: @Sean Lange I was thinking of the underlying datatype. This: `select case when convert(datetime,'19000101')=0 then 1 else 0 end` returns 1. But after your comment I checked the conversion table and noticed that although conversion from numeric datatypes to `datetime` is possible explicitly and implicitly, conversiont to `time` is not possible at all. One learns something new every day.

Comment: Yeah it is funky how the implicit conversions with date and time datatypes are so different.

Comment: The division is between the old types (datetime/smalldatetime) and the new types introduced in 2008 (date/time/datetime2/datetimeoffset). The latter inherited very few implicit behaviors (the most common gotcha is `getdate()+1` vs. `sysdatetime()+1`).

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE registrationDate = CONVERT(date, registrationDate);
```

Comment: what id date here ?

Comment: @Ishant Not understanding the question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: I need something like select * from table where registrationDate like "'%00:00:00.000";

Comment: Did you try what I posted instead of imagining what might work? A datetime column is not a string - that is just how tools like Management Studio present it to you. `LIKE` won't work the way you think.

Comment: if X is of type DATETIME, then CONVERT(date,X) will convert it to type DATE, which removes the time portion.  Then compare that to the original X.  The DATE will be converted back into a DATETIME by adding 00:00:00.000 time.  If the results are equal then the original must've had 00:00:00.000 time portion

Comment: @DavidDubois `date` has a **lower** precedance than `datetime`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017. In Aaron's expression `CONVERT(date, registrationDate)` will be implicitly converted back to a `datetime`, but will therefore have the time `00:00:00.000`, as it has been "lost".

Comment: And while it doesn't line up with exactly this use case, some [actual performance testing that shows this conversion is the most efficient way to strip time from datetime](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime) and [a follow-up here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time).

Comment: @Larnu, I agree. When comparing to the original "The DATE will be converted back into a DATETIME".

Answer (score 1):

See UPDATE below

```
Create Table #tbl
(
registrationDate Datetime
)
Insert Into #tbl Values
('2019-03-20 00:00:00.000'),
('2019-03-20 00:00:25.000')
```

Query

```
Select * From #tbl
Where Cast(registrationDate As Time) = '00:00:00.0000000'
```

Result:

```
registrationDate
2019-03-20 00:00:00.000
```

Update: If you really need to use "Like"

```
Select * From #tbl
Where convert(VarChar(50), registrationDate, 121) Like '%00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where FORMAT(registrationDate, 'HH:mm:ss:ms') ='00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: `FORMAT()` is actually [a pretty bad idea](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but), especially as part of a scan of the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

The following expression gets for every datetime value the corresponding date with time portion:

```
dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, '<date_time>'), 0)
```

Hence, the following will do the job:

```
create table foo (id int, registrationDate datetime)
insert foo values
   (1, '2019-04-04T03:22:48.00'),
   (2, '2019-04-04T00:00:00.00')
select * from foo
where registrationDate =
      dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, registrationDate), 0)
```